# Access to model relations in vue cart list l

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have an `add-to-cart` component and a `:book` prop in it. I pass the `$book` which is an object. In my book model I have `protected $with = ['genres','favourites'];` so that I can grab relation in my vue cart component.

However, when I see in the properties of book in my vue tool in inspect I don't see genres in there but I see favourites. Why is it so? I also tried accessing the relation like in my cart page I tried doing this `book.genres` but it gives me error!

Comment: Can you share more details of your `genres` and `favourites` attributes? Are they relationship or accessor?

Comment: Rather than describing the code, you should provide it as a [mcve]. Doing so would greatly improve your chances of getting a useful answer. If you need a multi-file node based environment use codesandbox.io or a similar online tool.